# What is going on inside "Forensic Watermarking" 0/1 Embedding into Video Frames?

Tags: video-watermarking

Hi Engineers & Developers!

Hope you are doing well. I am working with a "Forensic Watermarking" Solution and there is a process running which is called "Embedding 0/1". It embeds 0 or 1 into each video frames then encoded each frame. I am not clear actually what is happening inside the Embedder. Can you guys any idea ?

Regards
Tanmaya

Answer (score 1):

The embedder is 'hiding' information in the image for a particular frame.

The actual technique to hide that data may be different from implementation to implementation - there is quite a bit of literature and research in this domain, Steganography.

There is a very good summary in a recent IEEE paper:

- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9187785

(In case link breaks in future, paper is called 'Digital Steganography and Watermarking for Digital Images: A Review of Current Research Directions
OLEG EVSUTIN 1,3, ANNA MELMAN2,
AND ROMAN MESHCHERYAKOV3, (Senior Member, IEEE)')